# C# WPF ObservableCollection Add Method

Tags: c#, wpf, observablecollection

So I got `GetterSetter.cs` which is like this,

```
public string Name { get; set; }
```

and then `mainwindow.xaml.cs` i got this,

```
private ObservableCollection<GetterSetter> i = new ObservableCollection<GetterSetter>();
```

with this,

```
ObservableCollection<GetterSetter> g = new ObservableCollection<GetterSetter>()
        {
            new GetterSetter() {Name = textBoxName.Text }                               
        };
```

and I wanna do

```
i.Add(g);
```

but it wont let me how can i solve this?

Comment: do you want to add the first element from g to i? or all of the elements?

Comment: I wanna add name for right now but later I wanna add all of the elements

Comment: Just use foreach loop iterate the item and then add collection,or you want copy the x to y then use x.addrange(y)

Answer (score 2):

You cannot just add one collection to the other with ".Add()". That is just for assigning one value.

if you want the textbox value to directly be set the `i` then you can just do `i.Add(new GetterSetter{Name = textBoxName.Text});`

if `g` is a collection with multiple entries you can add all of them with

```
foreach( GetterSetter foo in g){
    i.Add(foo);
}
```

And if you don't have to use ObservableCollections specifically you can make them as lists. then you could just do `iAsList.AddRange(gAsList);`

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `Concat` method to *merge* two collections:

```
ObservableCollection<GetterSetter> a = new ObservableCollection<GetterSetter>();
ObservableCollection<GetterSetter> b = new ObservableCollection<GetterSetter>();

ObservableCollection<GetterSetter> c = new ObservableCollection<GetterSetter>(a.Concat(b));
```